# silverlight Best practices when to use visual States versus storyboards

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visualstatemanager

From what I have seen so far, it seems that you can use both visual states and storyboards to do the same thing visually to a silverlight application's UI. Am I wrong in making that statement? 
Does anyone here know of which one should be chosen over the other in a practical scenario?

Please excuse if my question is not specific enough. Im just a bit hazy on all things Silverlight. :)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question implies some conflict between Visual states and storyboards but no such conflict exists.

A `VisualState` **contains** a `Storyboard` which animates the visual change in the UI to represent the state.

Answer (score 1):

- If at the end of the animation your UI looks the same as before, use storyboard(s).
- If you cannot "design" the desired effect using states in Blend, use storeboards.
- Otherwise, use states.